# Laravel's Hash::check() and Auth::attempt() always returning false

Tags: php, laravel

The password is being hashed when it is registered.

```
$auth = Hash::check($request->get('password'), $user->password);
dd($auth);
```

I double checked the email input, password input and the hash, they are being output right, but still, both Hash::check() and Auth:attempt() dd output false

```
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
dd(Auth::attempt($credentials));
```

I'm testing it on a local environment with homestead, using Insomnia to post and test. Laravel 6 and PHP 7.3

My route in api routes file:

```
Route::post('/login','UserController@login');
```

The route is working, I have tested outputting the request data and they are right.

Thank you.

Comment: Unable to reproduce with that code, add the routes or any other code you suspect is related to the issue

Comment: @Saly3301 added my login route.

Comment: And the `UserController` class

Answer (score 0):

I had a method in my User Model class that hashed the password:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value){
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
}
```

and when I registered a new user either in Laravel's UI or seeds, I was hashing it again.
Removed the manual Hashing and now it all works fine.

Comment: Please be sure to accept your own answer so that the rest of the community knows that your problem is solved :)

Comment: Will do once it allows me to, 2 days left. Thanks!